# Codility “PermMissingElem” Solution

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, bitwise

This is my solution to the [PermMissingElem](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/3-time_complexity/perm_missing_elem/) problem, I wonder what can be improved? Expected worst case time complexity is O(N), but the performance test shows that it's O(N) or O(N * log(N)), which I suppose there's some solution out there that can truly achieve pure O(N)?

```
function solution(A) {
    const size = A.length;
    let sum = 0;

    for (i=0;i<size;i++){
        sum += A[i];
    }

    return (((size+ 1)*(size + 2))/2) - sum
}
```

The original problem is quoted as follows:

> A zero-indexed array A consisting of N different integers is given.
>   The array contains integers in the range [1..(N + 1)], which means
>   that exactly one element is missing.
>
> Your goal is to find that missing element.
>
> Write a function:
>
> int solution(int A[], int N); that, given a zero-indexed array A,
>   returns the value of the missing element.
>
> For example, given array A such that:
>
> A[0] = 2   A[1](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/3-time_complexity/perm_missing_elem/) = 3   A[2] = 1   A[3] = 5 the function should return
>   4, as it is the missing element.
>
> Assume that:
>
> N is an integer within the range [0..100,000]; the elements of A are
>   all distinct; each element of array A is an integer within the range
>   [1..(N + 1)].
>
> Complexity:
>
> expected worst-case time complexity is O(N); expected worst-case space
>   complexity is O(1), beyond input storage (not counting the storage
>   required for input arguments). Elements of input arrays can be
>   modified.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47471/perm-missing-elem-100-functional-score-but-only-60-performance) related question?

Comment: Can you share a performance test which reveals \$O(N\log{N})\$ complexity?

Comment: Just a note for people who may wonder at how the solution was arrived at. When you read the corresponding material at https://codility.com/media/train/1-TimeComplexity.pdf, accessed via https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/3-time_complexity/, it explains the optimal solution for finding the sum of integers 1..N. This solution can be applied to this problem, since we can find the sum of integers 1..N+1, and then subtract the sum of the integers in the array, in order to find the missing integer in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your JavaScript version, there is not much to optimize. So I am just going to provide some minor improvements:

1. Within a function, it is better to declare your variables using the `var` keyword. You should apply this to the `i` inside `for()` loop
2. The JavaScript interpreter is a single thread: this means, unfortunately, you can not perform real parallelism to sum different chunks of the array.
3. You can choose better variables and function names.

Answer (score 0):

A minor modification:

```
function solution(A) {
    const size = A.length;
    let sum = 0;

    for (let int of A){
        sum += int;
    }

    return (((size + 1)*(size + 2))/2) - sum
}
```

Note that I've kept the function name because it is what the exercises/tests in Codility use.

As noted in the lesson material, the input N is an integer within the range [0..100,000]; so \$O(n)\$ or \$O(N\log{N})\$  are acceptable time complexities. 
The dominant operation in this function is `sum += int;` (repeated in the loop N times). Other than that, we have a constant number of other operations, not e.g. [a nested loop where the input or another variable of the same order is halved in each iteration of the loop](https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-check-for-the-complexity-log-n-and-n-log-n-for-an-algorithm), which would be \$O(N\log{N})\$ time complexity. So both of our solutions are \$O(n)\$  complexity.